# Sync 1.7 TB data distributed across 3 directories from AWS S3 to Local Drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've 3 directories in S3 bucket and same 3 directories are there in a local drive (D:/). Total Size of 3 directories in S3 is 1.7 TB. What is the quickest way to sync data from S3 (all three directories) to a local drive?

Currently, my PowerShell script looks like below and it is taking 3 days for complete sync:

```
$servers = ("A","B","C")

# Going to sync all 3 servers at the same time to reduce the time the script runs for -------------
$servers | %{

  # Define what each job does
  $ScriptBlock = {
    param($pipelinePassIn)
    aws s3 --endpoint-url https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com --region eu-west-1 sync s3://$(bucketName)/$($pipelinePassIn) D:/backups/test/$($pipelinePassIn)
    Start-Sleep 6
  } 

  # Execute the jobs in parallel
  Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $_
}
```

Any response/feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: What type/speed of Internet connection do you have? Use a [bandwidth calculator](https://www.databarracks.com/support/bandwidth-calculator) to determine optimal transfer time. For example, you have a 10Gbps connection, it would take 17.5 days. Are you using a home Internet connection, or something in the workplace?